# Semaphore(int permits, boolean fair), what does fairness precisely do?

Tags: java, queue, semaphore, fifo

I need to implement a FIFO queue if there are not available permits on a semaphore.
My professor has specified that during the exam we will be able to use only the `acquire()` and `release()` methods.
My idea was to implement a LinkedList using the `tryAcquire()` method that if the result was false would add the currentThread at the bottom of the List.
Not being able to use the `tryAcquire()` method I searched and I noticed this construct.
If I initialize a semaphore, for example:

```
Semaphore example = new Semaphore(5, true);
```

What happens if a thread tries to use `acquire()` method on a semaphore that has exhausted its permits? Does it create a queue automatically? Do I have to handle it in any way or is the process automatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isn't the java doc explicit in this manner?

It says that the Thread calling `acquire` will be blocked until a permit is available as opposed to `tryAcquire` which will return false - meaning that there are no permits, but the Thread calling this method will not block.

Fairness is related. If there are already waiting threads but you `tryAcquire` via the current thread, it will ignore the fairness and get that permit. Since you are not allowed to use it, fairness *is* the FIFO queue that you are looking for. Literally from the doc:

> When fairness is set true, the semaphore guarantees that threads invoking any of the acquire methods are selected to obtain permits in the order in which their invocation of those methods was processed (first-in-first-out; FIFO)

If there are blocked threads, the two ways to un-block them would be to add a permit via `release` or interrupt the Thread - which I think you don't want to.

Comment: assuming that there are no permits and 4 Thread try to acquire one, will it automatically create a fifo queue? so I do not need any other additional structure?

Comment: @DarkPassenger that's what the documentation says, besides that is the only reasonable way to implement fairness IMO

Comment: the last thing, if I use the other constructor: 
Semaphore(int permits), it will manage a queue (not FIFO) or not?

Comment: @DarkPassenger It will be a queue, yes, but not a FIFO. i don't know what type it will be though